# No Template for LINQ to SQL in VS 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2017

I tried to open a DBML file recently, and when it didn't open correctly, I found out that I had to install the LINQ to SQL option for VS2017 Community.  I used the Visual Studio Installer to add the LINQ to SQL option.  When I reopened VS 2017 Community, DBML files opened correctly, but I still could not find the template for new DBML files (LING to SQL files).

How can I enable that template?

Comment: UPDATE: When I open the dbml file using VS 2017, it shows in the object view, (not code) but if I change anything in the dbml file, the code behind cs file does not update.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what helped me:

1. Quit Visual Studio 2017
2. Launch the Visual Studio Installer
3. Choose to modify the Visual Studio Installation
   [Visual Studio Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruaNx.png)
4. Click on "Individual Components", scroll down and click the checkbox next to "LINQ to SQL tools"
   [Individual Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEaX6.png)
5. Click "Modify" and then restart Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update your version of Visual Studio before the `modify` option displays.